# 2 Requisições AJAX com time diferente

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

queria alguma sugestão de como fazer 2 requisições ajax com tempo de execução diferente.

o que tenho até agora e que me atende bem é o seguinte.

```
function poll() {
setTimeout(function () {
GetData();
}, 60000); // 1 Minuto
}
function GetData() {
jQuery.ajax({
url: URL_BASE+"/orders_refresh.php", 
success: function(resultData) {
$('.Tela_atualizada').html(resultData); // DIV que será atualizada
},
error : function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
},
complete: function() {
poll();
},
timeout: 0,
});
}
poll();
```

O que eu estou querendo fazer é: Fazer uma **requisição** de imediato para preencher a **div** da página, para não ter que aguardar 1 minuto que ainda estar por vir.
ou seja.

Carregou a página já executo a **1 chamada** para popular a tabela da DIV.
e a partir daí eu posso aguardar a chamada seguinte que vai se repetir a cada minuto.
**obs**: essa primeira chamada só pode ser executada apenas uma vez. para não ficar um loop de 2 chamadas sem necessidade.

alguma sugestão?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Execute a função `GetData()` imediatamente sem o *timeout*. Basta colocar `GetData()` no fim do código.

Obs.: Eu organizei o código para ficar mais legível e caso queira que a requisição se repita a cada minuto, use setInterval().

```
function poll() {
    setTimeout(function() { // use setInterval() para repetir a chamada continuamente.
        GetData();
    }, 60000); // 1 Minuto
}

function GetData() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: URL_BASE + "/orders_refresh.php",
        success: function(resultData) {
            $('.Tela_atualizada').html(resultData); // DIV que será atualizada
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {},
        complete: function() {
            poll();
        },
        timeout: 0,
    });
}
poll();
GetData(); // <--- AQUI
```